# Creating 'Add to Calendar' Link, or Accept/Decline formatting in email?

Tags: apex, email-template, singleemailmessage

In gmail, when you get invited to an event, you get emails like this:

[image]

I am assembling emails to send to all invitees of an event with an email template in apex (template is in email template folder in SalesForce). Right now, I am creating an ics file that the user downloads and opens.

I am wondering, is it possible to get the kind of formatting in the gmail email event accept/decline like in the picture for emails sent to outlook, gmail, etc. with an ics file? Or if not an ics file, is it possible at all?

And if not possible, is it possible to have the ics file be a link instead of a download?

Comment: hey @tyler dahle, did you ever find an answer?    btw, it would be great to connect and talk about kendo +visualforce, i have seen your posts.  And anything salesforce/fullstack related.  If you visit my profile you'll find how to reach me

Cheers,

Comment: I found that a properly formatted ICS file will be interpreted by Google and show the event card with details about he event, but no Yes/No/Maybe options, just an 'add to calendar' link. Which is helpful. However, the 'owner' of the ics file will not see the event card in their email. Then use a button in the email to take users to a Force.com site that lets them accept/decline the event with a response. But that would be good. I have been doing nothing but Kendo/Visualforce/Apex/Salesforce integration :). Kendo has very powerful and sleek widget tools as well.